# Week Number in Q/KDB

Tags: kdb

I'm looking to map a date/week to the Week number of the year.

I've thought about subtracting the start of the year, and dividing by 7 - however it might not line up correctly.

```
e.g.
2020.01.02 -> Week 1
2020.01.06 -> Week 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use following function:

```
weekOfYear: {1+floor (x-`week$"d"$12 xbar"m"$x)%7}
```

This function

1. Finds the first Monday before or on 1st Jan. E.g. `` {(`week$"d"$12 xbar"m"$x)}2020.01.01 `` returns `2019.12.30`
2. Then finds difference in days between `x` and the first Monday
3. Divides difference by 7 and adds 1, which returns result you are looking for

For example

```
weekOfYear 2019.12.31 2020.01.01 2020.01.02 2020.01.05 2020.01.06 2020.01.07
```

returns

```
53 1 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on Antons great answer, you could also use the `div` function instead of flooring it, which would look something like

```
{1 + (x - `week $ `date $ 12 xbar `month $ x) div 7}
```